# SQL on joining tables (Month and subtextures that has no sales)

Tags: sql, derby

DBMS: Derby Embedded
Hello I wonder how I can make some outcome like

```
SubTextureID Year Month NetSales
1            2013 10    1000
2            2013 10    2000
3            2013 10    0
```

The third row never appears if that product 
has no sales(no records) in the order detail table
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Jack

```
   select  s.TextureName, s.SubTextureId,  sum(COALESCE(d.NetSales, 0)) NetSales
    from    (select SubTextureId, TextureName from subtexture) as s
    join
            (select SubTextureId, ProductCode from products) as p
        on  (p.SubTextureId = s.SubTextureId)
    left outer join
            (select ProductCode, OrderCode, NetSales from order_details) as d
        on  (d.ProductCode = p.ProductCode)
    left outer join
            (   select  YEAR(o.PurchaseDateTime) y,
                        MONTH(o.PurchaseDateTime) m,
                        OrderCode
                from    orders o
                where   o.PurchaseDateTime between '2013-11-01 00:00:00' and '2013-11-30 23:59:59' -- make use of an index if one exists
            ) as o
        on  (o.orderCode = d.orderCode)
    group by s.TextureName, s.SubTextureId, o.y, o.m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you used `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, try to use `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, if you understand what's difference about `LEFT` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, you will handle your problem

Comment: Hello, I changed it to right outer join, for both of them, but it doesn't make a difference. Any further advices?

Comment: can you give all table structure ?

Comment: 1) SubTexture - SubTextureID, TextureID, TextureName               2) Products - ProductID, ProductCode, SubTextureID, ProductName, UnitPrice                                                          3) Orders - OrderID, OrderCode, SKUCode, PurchaseDateTime         4) Order_Details - OrderDetailID, OrderCode, ProductCode, Quantity, Price, NetSales. Sorry when I press enter, add comments swing into action

Comment: try this SELECT st.SubTextureID,YEAR(od.PurchaseDateTime),MONTH(od.PurchaseDateTime),SUM(od.NetSales) 
FROM Order_Details od 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Products p ON p.ProductCode=od.ProductCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubTexture st ON p.SubTextureID=st.SubTextureID
GROUP BY p.ProductsID,YEAR(od.PurchaseDateTime),MONTH(od.PurchaseDateTime)